# When try to do Mysqldump Backup from console then getting such as error

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect

when i am tring to do MySQLDump backup from console then getting such as above error.
I am properly configure my MySQL Enterprise workbench and SQLyog ultimate tool. Able to do query and backup through that.

Kindly any one suggest me what i had mistake in system profile configuration of workbench.
I have check out my connection parameter that is ok.

Do i need to configure anything anywhere?
[image]

Comment: please check if the service is running

Comment: Yes service is running properly and also i am able to take backup from mysql workbench tool.

Comment: Is MySQL Server running on the standard port, 3306?  Adding `--port=3306` (or another port number, if you changed it) may help.  Error 10061 means there is no service listening on the port where the connection is trying  go ("connection refused.")

Comment: MySQL Server already --port=3306 had configured. There is no issue related to connection.

Comment: mysql> \s
mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for Win32 (x86)
Connection id:          4420
Current database:       -
Current user:           -
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.17-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:              -
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306

Comment: *There is no issue related to connection* -- well, yes, there is.  Error 10061 is absolutely an issue related to the connection.  Either your `my.ini` has spurious or inconsistent configuration in the `[client]` or `[mysqldump]` vs. the `[mysql]` section, or you are passing an argument to `mysql` (when you start the command line client) that you also need to pass to `mysqldump`, such as host or port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are able to start mysql from command line then there should be no error in taking dump as well

check to see if following command works, Either traverse to directory containing binaries or include them in path variable.
You can also include variables to include port,socket etc in your path.

> mysql.exe -uroot -p -P3306

In order to take mysqldump use following,use switches to your conveniences.

> mysqldump.exe -uroot -p -P3306 --all-databases --events >outfile.sql

Give It a try and let us know in case of any error.

**Regards and Happy New Year.**

Comment: C:\mysql-workbench-commercial-6.1.7-win32-noinstall\MySQL Workbench 6.1.7>mysql.exe -uroot -p -P3306
Enter password: ********
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: what does this gives in your workbench query   show variables like 'port'; I think you are using wrong connection parameters.

Comment: thanks for response , but getting the same error. Could you help me out for the specific connection parameters.

Comment: have you tried to figure out with which port mysql is connecting using the query in above comments?

Comment: port number 3306

Comment: mysql> status;
mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for Win32 (x86)

Connection id:          5263
Current database:      - 
Current user:          
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.17-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306

Comment: show variables like 'hostname'; and then use following command to connect mysql.exe -uroot -p<pass> -h<hostname> -P<port> and you should be able to connect to mysql. also check for client parameters in your related cnf file. Locate cnf file and then check for those parameters.

Comment: mysql> show variables where variable_name='hostname';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| hostname      | APPSVR |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) this is my connection hostname.

Comment: After tuning your instruction query got the error such as ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'APPSVR' (2)

Comment: ok what if you try following mysql.exe -uroot -p<password> --protocol=TCP -P<port>